# Check if ad completed ima sdk exo player

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer2.x, flutter-method-channel, imasdk

basically im trying to implement ima ads in exoplayer and then take the native view to flutter via method channel but im facing a problem and that's i want to track the status of ad completion so as soon an ad is completed i want to print ad completed or trigger a method from flutter but print will work for now

```
  import android.content.Context
  import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
  import android.net.Uri
  import android.view.LayoutInflater
  import android.view.View
  import com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.api.AdErrorEvent.AdErrorListener
  import com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.api.AdEvent.AdEventListener
  import com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.api.AdEvent.AdEventType
  import com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.api.AdsManager
  import com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.api.AdsManagerLoadedEvent
  import com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.api.ImaSdkFactory
  import com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.api.ImaSdkSettings
  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C
  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem
  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem.AdsConfiguration
  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.ima.ImaAdsLoader
  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.DefaultMediaSourceFactory
  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource
  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ads.AdPlaybackState
  //import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ads.AdsLoader
  import com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.api.AdsLoader;
  import com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.internal.ad

  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource
  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource
  import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util
  import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger
  import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
  import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
  import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformView


  internal class NativeView(context: Context, id: Int, creationParams: Map<String?, 
   Any?>?, messenger: BinaryMessenger,
    mainActivity: MainActivity
      ) : PlatformView,
    MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler ,AdsLoader.AdsLoadedListener{
     private val videoList = 
     listOf("https://storage.googleapis.com/gvabox/media/samples/stock.mp4",
        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos- 
    bucket/sample/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4")
    private var playerView: StyledPlayerView
    private var adsLoader: ImaAdsLoader? = null
//    private var eventListener: AdsLoader.? = null
    var player: ExoPlayer? = null
    var contentUri: Uri? = null
    var adTagUri: Uri? = null
    private val methodChannel: MethodChannel
    var imaSdkSettings: ImaSdkSettings?=null
    var imsdkgg: ImaSdkFactory?=null
    private var view: View = 
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_video_ad, null)
    private var adCompleted = false
    override fun getView(): View {
        return view
    }


    override fun dispose() {
        adsLoader!!.setPlayer(null)
        playerView.player = null
        player!!.release()
        player = null
        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    }

// callbacks for next, previous, pause and resume
    override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        when (call.method) {
            "loadUrl" -> {
                contentUri = Uri.parse(call.arguments.toString())

            }
            "pauseVideo" -> {
                player?.pause()
            }

            "loadpre" -> {
                val fff = call.arguments.toString()
                println("bvvvvvvvvvvv= $fff")

                player?.seekToPreviousMediaItem()

            }

            "loadnew" -> {
                val fff = call.arguments.toString()
                println("bvvvvvvvvvvv= $fff")

                player?.seekToNextMediaItem()

            }
            "resumeVideo" -> {
                player?.play()
            }
            else -> result.notImplemented()
        }
    }


    init {
        methodChannel = MethodChannel(messenger, "bms_video_player")
        methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
//        playerView = StyledPlayerView(context)

        playerView = view.findViewById(R.id.player_view)
// localization
        imsdkgg = ImaSdkFactory.getInstance()

            imaSdkSettings = imsdkgg!!.createImaSdkSettings()

        imaSdkSettings!!.language = "he"

        adsLoader = ImaAdsLoader.Builder(context).setImaSdkSettings(imaSdkSettings!!).build()
//adsManager.adProgressInfo.takeUnless {  }
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            initializePlayer(id, mainActivity, creationParams, methodChannel)
        }
    }


    private fun initializePlayer(
        id: Int,
        mainActivity: MainActivity,
        creationParams: Map<String?, Any?>?,
        methodChannel: MethodChannel
    ) {
// Set up the factory for media sources, passing the ads loader and ad view providers.
        val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(view.context)

        val mediaSourceFactory: MediaSource.Factory = DefaultMediaSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory)
            .setLocalAdInsertionComponents(
                { unusedAdTagUri: AdsConfiguration? -> adsLoader },
                playerView
            )

        player = ExoPlayer.Builder(view.context).setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory).build()
        playerView.player = player
        adsLoader!!.setPlayer(player)
//        adsLoader!!.adsLoader!!.addAdsLoadedListener(this)

        playerView.isControllerFullyVisible
        playerView.setShowNextButton(false)
        playerView.setShowPreviousButton(false)
        playerView.showController()
        playerView.useController = true
        playerView.controllerAutoShow = true

//        playerView.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT
//        playerView.controllerHideOnTouch = false

// Create the MediaItem to play, specifying the content URI and ad tag URI.
        contentUri = Uri.parse(creationParams?.get("videoURL") as String?)
        adTagUri =Uri.parse(creationParams?.get("adURL") as String?)

        println("myddddddddd=${contentUri.toString()}")

//        var adPlaybackState = AdPlaybackState(0, 500 * C.MICROS_PER_SECOND)
//        adPlaybackState = adPlaybackState.withAdCount(0,4)
//
//        eventListener?.onAdPlaybackState(adPlaybackState);


//        println("stateeee=${adPlaybackState}")
// Build the playlist.
        for (i in videoList.indices){
            var songPath:String = videoList.get(i)
            val item =Uri.parse(songPath)

            val contentStartmmm = MediaItem.Builder().setUri(item)
                .setAdsConfiguration(
                    AdsConfiguration.Builder(adTagUri!!).build()
                )                .setClipStartPositionMs(0).build()
            println("paliiyn comtent")
            player!!.addMediaItem(contentStartmmm)
        }
// Prepare the content and ad to be played with the SimpleExoPlayer.
        player!!.prepare()
// Set PlayWhenReady. If true, content and ads autoplay.
//        player!!.playWhenReady = false

        player!!.playWhenReady = true

    }
    private var adsManager: AdsManager? = null
    private val playAdsAfterTime = -1.0

    override fun onAdsManagerLoaded(adsManagerLoadedEvent: AdsManagerLoadedEvent?) {
        adsManager = adsManagerLoadedEvent!!.getAdsManager()

        // Attach event and error event listeners.

        // Attach event and error event listeners.
        adsManager!!.addAdErrorListener(
            AdErrorListener { adErrorEvent ->

                /** An event raised when there is an error loading or playing ads.  */
                /** An event raised when there is an error loading or playing ads.  */

            })
        adsManager!!.addAdEventListener(
            AdEventListener { adEvent ->

                /** Responds to AdEvents.  */
                /** Responds to AdEvents.  */
                if (adEvent.type != AdEventType.AD_PROGRESS) {
                    println("Event: " + adEvent.type)
                }
                when (adEvent.type) {
                    AdEventType.LOADED -> {
                        println("Ad fetch loaded")

                        adsManager!!.start()}
                    AdEventType.CONTENT_PAUSE_REQUESTED -> {}
                    AdEventType.CONTENT_RESUME_REQUESTED -> {}
                    AdEventType.PAUSED -> {
                        println("Ad fetch paused")

//                        isAdPlaying = false
//                        videoPlayerWithAdPlayback.enableControls()
                    }
                    AdEventType.RESUMED -> {
                        println("Ad fetch resumed")

//                        isAdPlaying = true
//                        videoPlayerWithAdPlayback.disableControls()
                    }
                    AdEventType.ALL_ADS_COMPLETED -> {
                       adCompleted = true
                        println("Ad fetch complete")
                        if (adsManager != null) {
                            adsManager!!.destroy()
                            adsManager = null
                        }
                        adsLoader!!.release()
                    }
                    AdEventType.AD_BREAK_FETCH_ERROR -> println("Ad Fetch Error. Resuming content.")
                    else -> {}
                }
            })
        val adsRenderingSettings = imsdkgg!!.createAdsRenderingSettings()
        adsRenderingSettings.setPlayAdsAfterTime(playAdsAfterTime)
        adsManager!!.init(adsRenderingSettings)
//        seek(playAdsAfterTime)
//        videoStarted = true

    }


    }
```